# Invalid storyboard when old version is installed on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Okay so here is the short breakdown. I have an app in the app store. I created a new version, in which I changed storyboard localization to base. Everything works fine on simulator and device.

The problem only occurs when I have the old (currently in app store) version on my device and try to test the new version with Xcode. The storyboard which is shown on the device is a mix between old and new version. New design but old arrangement. Because of my changes it crashes.

If I deleted the (old) app before I run the new version everything works fine.

So my questions are:

Will an app update delete all old cached storyboards?
Can I test my update after app store approval under "real" conditions? (I selected to release it manually.)
Obviously it is some kind of a problem with a cached version. Can I somehow make sure that the old storyboard won't be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have a problem, when an app is updated through the App Store, a new sandbox directory is created (at /var/mobile/Applications/) where the new version is installed, and the Library and Documents folder from the old installation are moved.

When using "build and run" in Xcode, it will only install the new files, so any files in the bundle that you have deleted in your new version will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: setting it here.setting it here.setting it here.setting it here.]setting it here.setting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename Storyboard file - it's weird but works.